# Mongoose 6 typescript doesn't allow $inc

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules

When migrating from mongoose 5.x to 6.x there was an error with the typescript, specifically with the UpdateQuery $inc as the type is set to undefined. I am using the built-in types not the `@types/mongoose` Here is an example:

```js
  export interface PrintSettings extends Document {
    _id: String
    currentBatch: Number
  }
  
  const PrintSettingsSchema: Schema<PrintSettings> = new Schema(
    {
      _id: { type: String },
      currentBatch: { type: Number, default: 0, min: 0 },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
    )
    
    let inc = await PrintSettingsModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: settingsId },
      { $inc: { currentBatch: 1 } }, // <------ Here is where the error occurs
      { useFindAndModify: false, new: true }
    )
```

The error I receive is this:

```js
   No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(filter: FilterQuery<PrintSettings>, update: UpdateQuery<PrintSettings>, options: QueryOptions & { rawResult: true; }, callback?: ((err: CallbackError, doc: any, res: any) => void) | undefined): Query<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ currentBatch: number; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(filter: FilterQuery<PrintSettings>, update: UpdateQuery<PrintSettings>, options: QueryOptions & { upsert: true; } & ReturnsNewDoc, callback?: ((err: CallbackError, doc: PrintSettings, res: any) => void) | undefined): Query<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ currentBatch: number; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(filter?: FilterQuery<PrintSettings> | undefined, update?: UpdateQuery<PrintSettings> | undefined, options?: QueryOptions | null | undefined, callback?: ((err: CallbackError, doc: PrintSettings | null, res: any) => void) | undefined): Query<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ currentBatch: number; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2769)
  index.d.ts(2576, 5): The expected type comes from property '$inc' which is declared here on type 'UpdateQuery<PrintSettings>'
```

Is this a type error with mongoose 6 or has the update or the atomic increment changed?

Comment: Are you using built in `index.d.ts` or are you using `@types/mongoose`? The official `index.d.ts` does include [$inc](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/index.d.ts#L2576). Can you check that file in node_modules mongoose to see if that line is present?

Comment: I am just using the built in types not the @types/mongoose

Comment: And if you go into node_modules mongoose do you see that line in the index.d.ts?

Comment: yes I see that line, the file is exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the casing of your `PrintSettings` interface. The types are expecting `PrintSettings.currentBatch` to be one of:

```
type _UpdateQuery<TSchema> = {
  // ...
  $inc?: OnlyFieldsOfType<TSchema, NumericTypes | undefined> & AnyObject;
  // ...
}

type NumericTypes = number | Decimal128 | mongodb.Double | mongodb.Int32 | mongodb.Long;
```

You are using `Number` instead of `number`, notice the lowercase "n". The following works:

```
export interface PrintSettings extends Document {
  _id: string;
  currentBatch: number;
}
```

Basically, for the interface use [everyday types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html). Which is slightly different than the types passed to the `Schema`.

Comment: In v5.x the typing would give me an error if I used number instead of Number but I am glad that is fixed now! Thank you.